# Server is slow when edit products or post

Tags: linux, mysql

I have a website in wordpress and Woocomerce and I have got 98000 products on it without images. I have dedicated server with 8core 2 ghz xeon processor, 12 GB RAM. It still exists the problem when I edit products in the WOOcomerce or edit the post

Editing of a product would last around 3 minutes, and also appears the message

> Connection Lost

And also the CPU usage jump at 80-100 %.

php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 512M
```

wp-config

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
```

How can this issue be solved?

Tuning MySQL Server Settings

```
[root@lnx-vps01 ~]# perl mysqltuner.pl

MySQLTuner 1.6.20 - Major Hayden major@mhtx.net
Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: root
Please enter your MySQL administrative password:
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.21-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 973M (Tables: 193)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 21M (Tables: 76)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 13h 41m 30s (2M q [46.245 qps], 21K conn, TX: 25G, RX: 400M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 94% / 6%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory : 11.6G
[--] Max MySQL memory : 6.3G
[--] Other process memory: 2.2G
[--] Total buffers: 5.7G global + 2.9M per thread (200 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 5.8G (50.42% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 6.3G (54.54% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 16% (32/200)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00% (1/21255)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 35.5% (1M cached / 3M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 225257
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 4% (6K temp sorts / 146K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 76% (149K on disk / 195K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (32 created / 21K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 74% (220 open / 294 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (247/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (1M immediate / 1M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 8 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.1.21-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 36.9% (198M used / 536M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 512.0M/323.9M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (1B cached / 97K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 15.5% (112K cached / 94K writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 100.0% (308M cached / 112K reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/21.5M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 4
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.97% (2335483 hits/ 2336273 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 27.16% (28436 hits/ 104699 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 76263 writes)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
query_cache_size (> 100M)
```

Comment: You have good latest InnoDB engine 10.1.21-MariaDB, but you use old MyISAM engine for your data. MyISAM doesn't give you performance with 21K connections.

Comment: You need to check if you have caching enabled in WP and if not, enable it.

Comment: I change MYISAM and innodb_buffer_pool_size=80 % of my RAM --innodb_log_buffer_size=25 % of my innodb_buffer_pool_size                                                                              
I have cashing enabled in WP

Comment: myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4096M
max_connections = 200
skip-name-resolve
key_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10240M
innodb_log_buffer_size=2560M
innodb_file_per_table=1
query_cache_size = 100M
wait_timeout = 120
tmp_table_size = 1024M
max_heap_table_size = 1024M
thread_cache_size = 100
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
query_cache_limit = 1024M
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
net_buffer_length=1M
table_open_cache=2500

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments due to low-rep, but to diagnose this issue better you will need to take a look at the actual query that's running and taking up all of your CPU and time. While your update script is running, login to mysql and type  `show full processlist`

Ideally, you will see a query that's running and using all of your CPU and runs for a while. Select the whole query and add `EXPLAIN` before it so that if the query that you are seeing is `select * from ....` make it `EXPLAIN select * from ...` which will print out query plan. You will most likely just need to add a couple indexes to make your queries run faster. This is most likely not a database setting issue, but implementation one.

Comment: myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4096M
max_connections = 200
skip-name-resolve
key_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10240M
innodb_log_buffer_size=2560M
innodb_file_per_table=1
query_cache_size = 100M
wait_timeout = 120
tmp_table_size = 1024M
max_heap_table_size = 1024M
thread_cache_size = 100
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
query_cache_limit = 1024M
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
net_buffer_length=1M
table_open_cache=2500